# UIPATH - Unknown type

Tags: c#, xaml, uipath

I'm trying to launch a workflow, previously saved in a xaml file with UIPath Studio, from a visual studio project (c#).

Here the code:

```
string pathToWorkflow = appl.Default.XAMLPath;
System.Activities.Activity workflowAsActivity = System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.Load(pathToWorkflow);
System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker invoker = new System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker(workflowAsActivity);
Dictionary<string, object> param = RiempiParam();
invoker.Invoke(param);
```

This code generate this exception:

> Impossibile creare il tipo sconosciuto (Impossible to create the unknown type)
>       '{http://schemas.uipath.com/workflow/activities}WindowScope'.

The project already refer to UiPath.Interop.dll, the same used in uipath studio.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

These means that you don't have the package of activity that defines WindowScope installed. This should be in the core activities. Any chance you removed it by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Dependencies Packages and make sure it's installed or doesn't require maintenance.
Had a similar problem before when downloading a project via Git as some of the dependencies weren't checked in by the other user.